# Get last month's Adsense profits via PHP

Tags: php, api, adsense

This question is asked in various forms (none too specific) on this site and I'd like to build a solution once and for all that attempts to conquer what are a LOT of confusing steps.

Loudly stated: **I need to extract my total adsense earnings from last month** for use with my website.

1. I realize this will require the Adsense API
2. I realize I'll need to provide credentials

A lot of existing Q&A on the matter refers to previous versions of Google's AdSense interface. I want to do this based on (as of) 2017.

#### THE QUESTION:

Will someone please provide an accurate, step-by-step and even over-explanatory instructional on how to do this complete with WHICH APIs are necessary and also their configuration?

I've attempted to go through the motions *many* times over and all I ever get (when I'm lucky enough to make the server/server handshake happen) is an error suggesting "must login" within the JSON output.

I've read some info on "solutions" for this but can't quite tell if either they don't work or my enabled API is incorrect (or misconfigured).

Comment: I understand that my question reads sharp but others who've asked the same have yet to receive a *working* solution - or - received partial, incomplete information which leads them to responding with "figured it out" and nothing beyond.

It's a simple goal. The negative response isn't called for.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the Google APIs PHP Client Library containing AdSense php samples, from

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation
```

Click on the GitHub link and you will go to this page

```
https://github.com/goog`le/google-api-php-client
```

You will get a folder called 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1' that you have to upload to yur server.

Click on the green button "Clone or Download".
Then download some examples for AD-SENSE from here

```
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples
```

Look at the file `googleads-adsense-examples-master/php-clientlib-1.x/v1.x/adsense-sample.php`
On this file set the constant STORE_ON_DISK to true. Better, you can look at the code of my own adsense-sample.php here below.

Edit the file `googleads-adsense-examples-master/php-clientlib-1.x/v1.x/client_secrets.json`
with your Credentials that you can get from your Google AdSense account
Get your Client ID from

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
```

The content of the file `googleads-adsense-examples-master/php-clientlib-1.x/v1.x/client_secrets.json` should look like

```
{
    "web":
    {
        "client_id":"youridblablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id":"yournameproject",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret":"blablabla",
        "redirect_uris":["http://yourdomain.com/thepathtoyoursamplephpfile"],
        "javascript_origins":["http://yourdomain.com/","http://yourdomain.com/"]
    }
}
```

Get your Publisher ID from here `https://www.google.com/adsense/` then go to the Settings/Account Information panel

--

This is the way I modify the sample code and get it working.
Put the APIs folder google-api-php-client-2.1.1 within the folder containing this php file (see php code here below).
Create a folder AdSense_Report within the folder 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1'
Copy all the sample files (CollateReportData.php, FillMissingDatesInReport.php, GenerateReport.php...)
within the folder AdSense_Report. So you can include the sample files this way:

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllAccounts.php';
```

Rename and put the my_project_client_secrets.json within the folder 'AdSense_Report'.
Be sure the file `my_project_client_secrets.json` is not readable by others, but only by this php.
This is my php code. I commented some unwanted function.

```
function UserBannerRevenueReportGoogle()
{
    define('MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE', 50, true);
    define('MAX_REPORT_PAGE_SIZE', 50, true);

    define('STORE_ON_DISK', true, true);
    define('TOKEN_FILENAME', 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/google_adsense_tokens.dat', true);
    define('CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_PATH', 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/my_project_client_secrets.json', true);

    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/templates/base.php';

    session_start();

    /*
    // In case of trouble, reset the token by activating these lines, call the script, then comment these lines back.
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    @unlink(TOKEN_FILENAME);
    return;
    */

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON_PATH);


    $service= new Google_Service_AdSense($client);
    // If we're logging out we just need to clear our local access token.
    // Note that this only logs you out of the session. If STORE_ON_DISK is
    // enabled and you want to remove stored data, delete the file.
    if(isset($_REQUEST['logout']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
        @unlink(TOKEN_FILENAME);
    }

    // If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow, we need to exchange that
    // with the authenticate() function. We store the resultant access token
    // bundle in the session (and disk, if enabled), and redirect to this page.
    if(isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        // Note that "getAccessToken" actually retrieves both the access and refresh
        // tokens, assuming both are available.
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        if(STORE_ON_DISK){
            file_put_contents(TOKEN_FILENAME, $_SESSION['access_token']);
        }
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ."?ta=54";
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        exit;
    }

    // If we have an access token, we can make requests, else we generate an authentication URL.
    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
    else if(STORE_ON_DISK && file_exists(TOKEN_FILENAME) && filesize(TOKEN_FILENAME) > 0)
    {
        // Note that "setAccessToken" actually sets both the access and refresh token,
        // assuming both were saved.
        $client->setAccessToken(file_get_contents(TOKEN_FILENAME));
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
    else
    {
        // If we're doing disk storage, generate a URL that forces user approval.
        // This is the only way to guarantee we get back a refresh token.
        if(STORE_ON_DISK){
            $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        }
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    }


    echo pageHeader('AdSense Management API sample');
    echo '<div><div class="request">';
    if(isset($authUrl))
    {
        echo '<a class="login" href="' . $authUrl . '">Connect Me!</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a class="logout" href="?ta=54&logout">Logout</a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';


    if($client->getAccessToken())
    {
        echo '<pre class="result">';
        // Now we're signed in, we can make our requests.
        UserBannerRevenueReportGoogleGet($service);

        // Note that we re-store the access_token bundle, just in case anything
        // changed during the request - the main thing that might happen here is the
        // access token itself is refreshed if the application has offline access.
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
    echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
}



function UserBannerRevenueReportGoogleGet($service)
{
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllAccounts.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAccountTree.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllAdClients.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllAdUnits.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllCustomChannelsForAdUnit.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllCustomChannels.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllUrlChannels.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GenerateReport.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GenerateReportWithPaging.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/FillMissingDatesInReport.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/CollateReportData.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllSavedReports.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GenerateSavedReport.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllSavedAdStyles.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllAlerts.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllDimensions.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.1.1/AdSense_Report/GetAllMetrics.php';

    $accounts = new GetAllAccounts;

    print "\n";
    $accounts = GetAllAccounts::run($service, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);

    if(isset($accounts) && !empty($accounts))
    {
        // Get an example account ID, so we can run the following sample.
        $exampleAccountId = $accounts[0]['id'];
        //GetAccountTree::run($service, $exampleAccountId);
        $adClients = GetAllAdClients::run($service, $exampleAccountId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);

        $bullets = str_repeat('#', 80) . "\n";
        if(isset($adClients) && !empty($adClients))
        {
            foreach($adClients as $exampleAdClient)
            {
                // Get an ad client ID (the last one), so we can run the rest of the samples.
                //$exampleAdClient = end($adClients); // to get the first ID use: $adClients[0];
                $exampleAdClientId = $exampleAdClient['id'];

                print $bullets;
                print "AdClient: ".$exampleAdClientId." - ".$exampleAdClient['productCode']."\n";
                print $bullets;

                $adUnits = GetAllAdUnits::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
                if(isset($adUnits) && !empty($adUnits))
                {
                    // Get an example ad unit ID, so we can run the following sample.
                    //$exampleAdUnitId = $adUnits[0]['id'];
                    //GetAllCustomChannelsForAdUnit::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId, $exampleAdUnitId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
                }
                else{
                    print 'No ad units found, unable to run dependant example.\n';
                }


                /*

                $customChannels = GetAllCustomChannels::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
                if(isset($customChannels) && !empty($customChannels))
                {
                    // Get an example ad unit ID, so we can run the following sample.
                    $exampleCustomChannelId = $customChannels[0]['id'];
                    GetAllAdUnitsForCustomChannel::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId, $exampleCustomChannelId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
                }
                else{
                    print 'No custom channels found, unable to run dependant example.\n';
                }
                */

                //GetAllUrlChannels::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
                GenerateReport::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId);
                //GenerateReportWithPaging::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId, MAX_REPORT_PAGE_SIZE);
                //FillMissingDatesInReport::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId);
                //CollateReportData::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleAdClientId);
            }
        }
        else{
            print 'No ad clients found, unable to run dependant examples.\n';
        }

        print $bullets;
        print $bullets;
        $savedReports = GetAllSavedReports::run($service, $exampleAccountId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
        if(isset($savedReports) && !empty($savedReports))
        {
            // Get an example saved report ID, so we can run the following sample.
            $exampleSavedReportId = $savedReports[0]['id'];
            GenerateSavedReport::run($service, $exampleAccountId, $exampleSavedReportId);
        }
        else{
          print 'No saved reports found, unable to run dependant example.<br>';
        }

        //GetAllSavedAdStyles::run($service, $exampleAccountId, MAX_LIST_PAGE_SIZE);
        GetAllAlerts::run($service, $exampleAccountId);
    }
    else{
        print 'No accounts found, unable to run dependant examples.\n';
    }

    GetAllDimensions::run($service);
    GetAllMetrics::run($service);
}
```